# Incompatible Type error on same type when using Comparator

Tags: java, generics, comparator

I have a generic class called `Interval`

```java
package com.test;

//import statements

public class Interval<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

    private boolean isStartInclusive;
    private T start;
    private T end;
    private boolean isEndInclusive;

    //Constructors

    //Getter and Setters

    //ToString

    //Hashcode and Equals

    //A public static method that returns comparator for use by other classes
    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<Interval<T>> getIntervalComparator() {
        return (o1, o2) -> {
            //comparing logic that returns -1 or 1 or 0
        };
    }

}
```

Whenever I use this `Comparator` to sort a `List<Interval<T>>` it works.

```java
List<Interval<T>> intervalsList1 = getIntervalsList();
intervalsList1.sort(Interval.getIntervalComparator());
```

But when I do this

```java
List<Interval<T>> intervalsList1 = getIntervalsList1();
List<Interval<T>> intervalsList2 = getIntervalsList2();

Interval<T> interval1 = intervalsList1.get(i);
Interval<T> interval2 = intervalsList2.get(i);

int compareOneVsTwo = Interval.getIntervalComparator().compare(interval1, interval2); //line 85
```

I get an error saying

```java
Error:(85, 76) java: incompatible types: com.test.Interval<T> cannot be converted to com.test.Interval<T>
```

Even when I do this

```java
Interval<Integer> integerInterval1 = new Interval<>(true, 1, 2, true);
Interval<Integer> integerInterval2 = new Interval<>(true, 4, 5, true);
int compareOneVsTwo = Interval.getIntervalComparator().compare(integerInterval1, integerInterval2); //line 115
```

I get this error:

```java
Error:(115, 72) java: incompatible types: com.test.Interval<java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to com.test.Interval<T>
```

I do not understand what is causing this compilation error. The comparator inside the `Interval` class is not the natural sort order, but the order in which multiple classes use when they sort for their own purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you separate the statement into two separate statements:

```
Comparator<Interval<T>> compareOneVsTwo = Interval.getIntervalComparator();
compareOneVsTwo.compare(interval1, interval2);

// or in the integer case:
Comparator<Interval<Integer>> compareOneVsTwo = Interval.getIntervalComparator();
compareOneVsTwo.compare(interval1, interval2);
```

(assuming `T` is an existing type)

This is because when they are the same statement, the compiler is not smart enough to know that you need a `Comparator<Interval<Integer>>`. You could need a `Comparator<Interval<String>>` or a `Comparator<Interval<LocalDate>>`, as far as the compile is concerned, **because it doesn't look at the `.compare` call when inferring the type parameters for the `getIntervalComparator` call.**

What happens when the compiler doesn't know? It uses the type bound on the type parameter, i.e. `Comparable<? super T>`, so it thinks you need a `Comparator<Interval<T>>`, but `T` doesn't actually exist...

Another way to fix this is:

```
Interval.<Integer>getIntervalComparator().compare(...)
```